# Replace Value in Column with Value in Different Column

Tags: sql, if-statement, replace, coalesce, aginity

I have a dataset that looks like this in SQL.

```
Col1     Col2     Col3     
   A        4        1
   B        5     NULL 
   C        6        1
   D        7     NULL
   E        8     NULL
```

How do I add a new column with the values in Col2 with the values in Col3 if Col3 = 1, or else keep the existing values in Col2.

Final Expected Output:

```
Col1     Col2     Col3     Col4     
   A        4        1        1
   B        5     NULL        5
   C        6        1        1
   D        7     NULL        7
   E        8     NULL        8
```

I tried the coalesce function but I don't think that worked:

```
SELECT 
Col1, 
Col2, 
Col3,
coalesce(Col3, Col2) AS Col4
FROM table1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  `COALESCE()` should do what you want.

Comment: Left justified SQL is very hard to read. Proper formatting makes everything much easier.

Comment: It should be: coalesce(Col3, Col2)

Comment: thanks that's what I meant to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description suggests a `case` expression :

```
select . . . 
       (case when col3 = 1 then col3 else col2 end) as col4
```

You could also express the above as

```
select . . . 
       (case when col3 = 1 then 1 else col2 end) as col4
```

For the data you provided, `coalesce()` should also work.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this out in a couple hours and let you know! This looks like it should work, appreciate the help

Comment: In my example, does it look like I am using coalesce right?

Comment: @NickKnauer . . . Yes.  You are using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    Col1, 
    Col2, 
    Col3,
    CASE WHEN Col3 IS NOT NULL THEN Col3 ELSE Col2 END AS Col4
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- this should do what you want
SELECT 
Col1, 
Col2, 
Col3,
CASE WHEN Col3 = 1 THEN Col3 ELSE Col2 END AS NewCOL
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into table2
select 
Col1, 
Col2, 
Col3, 
(case when col3 = 1 then 1 else col2 end) as col4
FROM table1
```

Comment: A bit of elaboration on why this works would help future people with the same issue understand the solution.